# How can I pull data from Excel and transfer it to existing charts and tables on Powerpoint using Python?

Tags: python, excel, powerpoint

Every week, I get sent the same excel files but with different values that are updated. What I usually do is manually pull these values from excel, and put them into the same charts and graphs in Powerpoint to update them. For example, if I get updated values for the 2nd week of July, I get these values, open PowerPoint, open the graph, and insert a new date with the corresponding values. This usually takes me a few hours a week to do. Is there any way I can run a script that would take the values of the excel file once I download them, and add them to my tables and graphs on my existing PowerPoint file? If so, how can I do it and what libraries can I use? Or is there a better way that I can automate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a fairly common use-case for `python-pptx`. You'll have to search separately for each of the finer points, but here's a general strategy I've seen work many times:

1. Use `openpyxl` to read the values you need from the Excel workbook (.xlsx file).
2. Use a "template" .pptx file that looks like the final product you want each week except the updatable values aren't up-to-date. This could be a special .pptx file you keep for this purpose or it could just be the one from last week. I recommend you start with the one from last week and then always use that same one as your template. That just keeps things more predictable. You would start by calling `prs = Presentation("my-template.pptx")` to begin the process.
3. Find the chart that needs updating. If you always use the same template that can just be `chart = prs.slides[3].shapes[6].chart` or whatever the right numbers are because it's always in the same place.
4. Create a new `ChartData` object containing the new numbers.
5. Call `chart.replace_chart_data(new_chart_data)` to replace the chart values.
6. Then `prs.save(new_name_for_this_week)` and you're done.

The `python-pptx` documentation is here: https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

I'd say work through the Getting Started exercise just as a warm-up and then to this example: https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/charts.html

After that, Google is your friend and most roads lead back here to StackOverflow where there are more that 500 questions with answers about specific aspects of `python-pptx`.